# How to use 'DBCPConnectionPoolLookup' controllor service in 'ExecuteGroovyScript' processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to access multiple databases depending on the 'database.name' attribute sent in the input flowfile to ExecuteGroovyStript processor.

In 'ExecuteGroovyStript' processor I have a property 'SQL.clientdb' which point to 'lookup' service. At the same time I have commissioned a 'DBCPConnectionPool' service with all the required details and its 'name' property similar to value of 'database.name'.
The way in which I'm trying to access the pool service is:
 `def clientDb = SQL.clientdb.getConnection(flowFile.getAttributes())`

Error which I receive after running the Groovy processor is
`org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Attributes must contain an attribute name 'database.name': org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Attributes must contain an attribute name 'database.name'`

Please find below links of images which shows further details:

1. [Configuration of 'ExecuteScript'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmXMs.jpg)
2. [Connection pool services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHBFo.jpg)
3. [Attributes of input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cojej.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [additional details](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/additionalDetails.html) documentation of the [ExecuteGroovyScript processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/index.html)

For all `SQL.*` parameters connection to the database obtained from corresponding connection pool automatically on trigger. And `SQL.xxx` variable references [groovy.sql.Sql object](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html)

If you want to access any controller service - use `CTL.` prefix for your parameter.

In this case the variable `CTL.xxx` provides a link to a ControllerService directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked, when 'SQL.' is used in the 'executeGroovyScript' the 'Lookup' service shows up in the drop sown, that is where I got confused. But now I'm facing another issue. Lookup is able to find the service but gives the following exception `java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object`, while when I directly use the 'DBCPConnectionPool' service instead of 'Lookup' service it works as expected. Please help.

Comment: Please create another question and provide more details on it: code, full stack trace...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57888447/exception-cannot-get-a-connection-pool-error-timeout-waiting-for-idle-object

Please have a look, Thanks

Comment: if you can point me to an example where lookup service is used in groovy script, that would be very helpful, thanks.