# Exception 'Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object' when using 'DBCPConnectionPoolLookup' service in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to use 'DBCPConnectionPoolLookup' service in 'ExecuteGroovyScript' to dynamically query the required database based on 'database.name' parameter in the input flow file.

The processor is successfully able to get the corresponding 'DBCPConnectionPool' service for querying but I'm getting the an exception `java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object`. As opposed to if I directly use the 'DBCPConnectionPool' service without the 'Lookup' service without changing any configuration it works fine.
I access the service as follows:

`def clientDb = CTL.SQLLookupService.getConnection(flowFile.getAttributes())`

Then use the 'clientDb' object to query as:
`clientDb.rows(timseriesSqlCountQuery).eachWithIndex { row, idx ->numRowsTimeSeries= row.c}`

I have tried increasing the values of `Max Wait Time` and `Max Total Connections` to higher values in  'DBCPConnectionPool' service, it does not help.

Please find below detail links of images for code,error and configuration

1. [Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOJHZ.jpg)
2. [Configuration of 'ExecuteGroovyScript'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcwfx.jpg)
3. [Configuration of 'DBCPConnectionPool' service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnDfD.jpg)
4. [Configuration of 'DBCPConnectionPoolLookup' service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29aXp.jpg)

Script Code

```
import org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.Deserializer
import org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.Serializer
import org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.exception.DeserializationException
import org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.exception.SerializationException
import groovy.sql.Sql

import java.time.*

try {
    def flowFile = session.get()

    def isBootstrap=flowFile."isBootstrap"

    def timseriesSqlQuery='SELECT id FROM [dbo].[Points] where ([MappedToEquipment] = \'Mapped\' or PointStatus = \'Mapped\')'
    def timseriesSqlCountQuery='SELECT count(id) as c FROM [dbo].[Points] where ([MappedToEquipment] = \'Mapped\' or PointStatus = \'Mapped\')'

    def spaceSqlQuery='select id from (select id from dbo.organization union select id from dbo.facility union select id from dbo.building union select id  from dbo.floor union select id from dbo.wing union select id from dbo.room union select id from dbo.systems) tmp'
    def spaceSqlCountQuery='select count(id) as c from (select id from dbo.organization union select id from dbo.facility union select id from dbo.building union select id  from dbo.floor union select id from dbo.wing union select id from dbo.room union select id from dbo.systems) tmp'


    def cache = CTL.lastIngestTimeMap

    def clientDb = CTL.SQLLookupService.getConnection(flowFile.getAttributes())//SQL.staticService

    int numRowsTimeSeries=0
    int numRowsSpace=0

    clientDb.rows(timseriesSqlCountQuery).eachWithIndex { row, idx ->numRowsTimeSeries= row.c}
    clientDb.rows(spaceSqlCountQuery).eachWithIndex { row, idx ->numRowsSpace= row.c}
}
```

Exception from Nifi logs

```
2019-09-12 06:18:33,629 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.n.p.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript ExecuteGroovyScript[id=b435c079-ee6c-3c42-a6ea-020968267ecf] ExecuteGroovyScript[id=b435c079-ee6c-3c42-a6ea-020968267ecf] failed to process session due to java.lang.ClassCastException; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.ClassCastException
java.lang.ClassCastException: null
2019-09-12 06:18:33,629 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.n.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask Administratively Yielding ExecuteGroovyScript[id=b435c079-ee6c-3c42-a6ea-020968267ecf] due to uncaught Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException
java.lang.ClassCastException: null
2019-09-12 06:18:33,629 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9] o.a.n.p.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript ExecuteGroovyScript[id=9b81ca15-93a5-3953-9f40-d0874cfe2531] ExecuteGroovyScript[id=9b81ca15-93a5-3953-9f40-d0874cfe2531] failed to process session due to java.lang.ClassCastException; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.ClassCastException
java.lang.ClassCastException: null
2019-09-12 06:18:33,629 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9] o.a.n.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask Administratively Yielding ExecuteGroovyScript[id=9b81ca15-93a5-3953-9f40-d0874cfe2531] due to uncaught Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException
java.lang.ClassCastException: null
2019-09-12 06:18:33,708 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.n.p.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript ExecuteGroovyScript[id=a1ec4496-dca3-38ab-a47b-43d7ff95e40f] org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:308)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(DBCPService.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:84)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript.onInitSQL(ExecuteGroovyScript.java:339)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript.onTrigger(ExecuteGroovyScript.java:439)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1165)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:203)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:142)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:305)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:451)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:365)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
2019-09-12 06:18:33,708 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.p.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript ExecuteGroovyScript[id=54d1e251-88f2-33f3-0489-722879a802bd] org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:308)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(DBCPService.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:84)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript.onInitSQL(ExecuteGroovyScript.java:339)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript.onTrigger(ExecuteGroovyScript.java:439)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1165)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:203)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:142)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:305)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:451)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:365)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: There should be no difference going through the lookup vs going directly to the service, the lookup service is just a pass through that selects a specific DBCP service

Comment: Can you show your whole script where you use the service?

Comment: @Omkar, could you provide the fill stacktrace from log and which line of script throws exception.

Comment: @Bryan I have posted the shortened version of the script please take a look

Comment: @dagget, I'm trying to solve this issue since I posted it, one important thing I observed is even if I don't use 'lookup' service in the script, but keep it configured in the processor, I'm still receiving the same error, and the I/P flow files don't get processed

Comment: Do some of the calls to the script work and then start failing, or does it never work?

Comment: @BryanBende it never works

Comment: @daggett please ignore the comment 'I don't use 'lookup' service in the script, but keep it configured in the processor, I'm still receiving the same error'. That's not the case, the error only occurs when I use 'CTL.lookupName' in my script.

Comment: Guys, one more important observation, I left the 'lookup' service enabled overnight by mistake, in the morning I saw all the processors which were using the 'DBCPConnectionPool' service started throwing the same exception. I have updated the question with stack trace from Nifi logs. I had to restart the VM to get Nifi working again. I'm starting to think this is a bug in the 'Lookup' service in Nifi 1.8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after bring down Nifi twice I have found the solution. The problem seemed to be in the code which I was using, I used the object returned by `CTL.index.getConnection(flowFile.getAttributes())` to query the SQL table which actually is a connection table, now due to this Nifi used up all available connections to SQL, due to which even if I reverted to using 'DBCPConnectionPool' service instead if 'Lookup' I was getting the above error. When I used to restart Nifi it used to work fine.

The actual code to be used in your script for using 'Lookup' Service is

```
def connectionObj = CTL.index.getConnection(flowFile.getAttributes())
def clientDb = new Sql(connectionObj)
```

Now use the 'clientDb' object to query your table

`clientDb.rows(timseriesSqlCountQuery).eachWithIndex { row, idx ->numRowsTimeSeries= row.c}`

Comment: ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.n.p.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript ExecuteGroovyScript[id=94741875-1003-1179-34a1-12877913982c] java.lang.RuntimeException: The `CTL.index` not defined in processor properties